# How to pass in a callable object into a template class's constructor, able to call it later?

Tags: c++, c++17

I want a class template whose constructor accepts (among other things), a callable argument. The class can then store a reference/pointer to this callable object and later call the function. I'll try to sketch out what I'm looking for here:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(T _a, Callable& _f)
  : a(_a)
  , f(_f)
  {}

  float getFloat() {
    return f(a);
  }

private:
  T a;
  Callable f;
};

static float minus1(int num) {
  return num - 1;
}

class Stateful {
public:
  Stateful()
  : num_calls(0)
  {}

  float operator()(int num) {
    ++num_calls;
    return static_cast<float>(num) - (static_cast<float>(num_calls) * 0.5);
  }
private:
  int num_calls;
};

static std::function<float(float)> invert = [](float a){ return -a; };


MyClass<int> option1(-5, &minus1);
MyClass<int> option1a(99, &minus1);
option1.getFloat(); // -6
option1a.getFloat(); // 98

static Stateful stateful{};
MyClass<int> option2(10, &stateful);
option2.getFloat(); // 9.5
option2.getFloat(); // 9

MyClass<int> option2a(100, &stateful);
option2a.getFloat(); // 98.5
option2.getFloat(); // 8

MyClass<float> option3(1.602, &invert);
MyClass<float> option3a(-6.022, &invert);
option3a.getFloat(); // 6.022
option3.getFloat(); // -1.602

float pi = 3.14f;
MyClass<bool> option4(true, [&pi](bool b){return (b ? pi : 0.f);};
option4.getFloat(); // -3.14
```

I know I can solve this somewhat with some classical inheritance, i.e. use some `BaseCallable` subclass in `MyClass` and have all client `Callable` types inherit from that subclass. However, I don't like this because it would be nice to be able to pass in a lambda, or a std::function, into `MyClass`.

I tried using `Callable` as a template, but I don't like this approach because I am using a variant so that I can have a container of `MyClass`:

```
using Element = variant<MyClass<int>, MyClass<float>, MyClass<bool>>;
vector<Element> vec;
...
```

and I think the idea is unworkable if there is another template parameter there, especially with lambda types.

I've tried implementing Callable as a type erasure Concept, which I think is the best way to go here but I can't seem to get it to work without throwing exceptions due to the internal shared_ptr of `f` being nullptr in the `getFloat()` call. Any help here would really be greatly appreciated!

EDIT to add how the vector is used:

```
using Element = variant<MyClass<int>, MyClass<float>, MyClass<bool>>;
vector<Element> vec;

vec.push_back(option1);
vec.push_back(option2);
vec.push_back(option2a);
vec.push_back(option3);
vec.push_back(option3a);
vec.push_back(option4);

for (auto& option : vec) {
  std::visit([](auto&& arg) { std::cout << arg.getFloat() << std::endl; }, option);
}
```

EDIT2: final working version following @aschepler's answer: https://godbolt.org/z/MbdK8o891

Comment: Your `getFloat()` definition seems to be missing the `return` keyword.

Comment: `static Stateful stateful();` declares a function (a Most Vexing Parse).

Comment: @aschepler Thanks, good catch. This isn't my real code btw, I tried to just create an example to show the problem I'm having

Comment: Extra template parameter, fix couple typos [and it works](https://godbolt.org/z/Kqfh5js11). Solution with `std::function` is nice too.

Comment: @MarekR looks good, but unfortunately then I can't have a container of `MyClass` - at least not using the variant method I described in the post

Comment: IMO you should describe how you use this `vector` since it is strange to have container of something callable with different types of arguments. It is more probable that you need multiple `std::vectors<MyClass<T>>...` then having single one `std::vector<std::variant<MyClass<int>, ...`.

Comment: @MarekR fair enough, I've updated the original post. For now, the `std::function` approach from @aschelper is good enough anyway

Comment: So basically your `MyClass` does something similar to `std::bind` or lambda, it just captures single argument. From that point of view `MyClass` is obsolete and `std::variant` too. https://godbolt.org/z/cn8zvenPT So you made this over-complicated or you didn't provide most important thing into a question.

Comment: @MarekR yeah there are other things that `MyClass` does in the real project which means it needs to exist, and there needs to be a variant over it. I didn't include those other details as I didn't think they were relevant to what I'm working on now, which is adding the ability of `MyClass` to accept a callable object in its constructor. But you're right that in this stripped down example it seems like it could be obsolete

Comment: @Robert it doesn't meter what `MyClass` class does. It is more important what you do with vector. Looks like you need `std::vector<std::function<float()>>` and fact that `MyClass` will be inside is unimportant implementation detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tried implementing Callable as a type erasure Concept

That's a good idea, but the implementation has already been done for you. Use the type `std::function<float(T)>` as your `Callable`. The template argument to `std::function` is a function type, written in general as `ReturnType(ParamType1, ParamType2,`...`)`.

See [std::function on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: Aha maybe it could be so simple! The only issue I have left with this is in the case of passing a callable object (option2 in the example): https://onlinegdb.com/yqNanX0JO . It's copying the `stateful` object, and I can't find any combination of references/pointers to get it to only keep a reference of the object so that it can be used for multiple`MyClass`s

Comment: Oh, I see. You can do `MyClass<int> option2(10, std::ref(stateful));`, since a `std::reference_wrapper<T>` is callable if its `T` is callable.

Comment: Maybe your stateful callable can be implemented by keeping a `std::shared_ptr` to the actual stateful object. This way the std::function callable can be copied.

Comment: Thanks aschepler and @wohlstad, I've tried both of your suggestions, but I can't quite get it to work. Anyway, I've reviewed my requirements and simply being able to accept functions, std::functions, and lambdas is enough for now. If no one else comes forward with a solution to allow the stateful callable class to also fit in, then I'll accept this answer in a while

Comment: update: got the `std::ref` idea working